# How to detect object clicked in WebGL?

Tags: webgl, raytracing

Firstly, I am not using 3Js in my [Orbits](https://gpsanimator.com/orbits) app because I encountered a number of limitations including, but not limited to, issues with texture resolution and my requirement for complex lighting equations but I would like to implement something like 3Js' raycaster to allow me to detect the object clicked by the user.

I'm new to WebGL, but an "old hand" in software development so I'm looking for some hints about where to start.

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is "object picking".

Comment: OK, Thanks. I see I can use  use gl.readPixels to relate the click to the display, but then what approach is suggested to determine which object the pixels belong to?

Comment: Is there a non-displaying attribute of the pixel I can use to identify the object (I only have 20-odd objects so could encode an object ID for example)

Comment: The raycaster is cpu based. It transforms a 3D ray into model space for each model and walks every triangle in that model doing a ray to triangle intersection check. For gpu based there [this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-picking.html) style. The both have their tradeoffs.

Answer (score 0):

The approach is as follows:

You generate your scene twice, once normally which is displayed and the second, with the objects uniquely coloured but not displayed. Then you use gl.readPixels from the second scene using the position on the first and decode the colour to identify the object.

Now I have to implement it myself.

Comment: If your objects are planets (sphere like), or widely separated, you can use distance point (object center) is from a ray (projected mouse ray). The operation is trivial compared to what you describe

Answer (score 0):

### Picking spheres

When picking spheres, or objects that are separated (not one inside another) you can use a simple distance from ray to very quickly get the closest object.

### Example

The function returns a function that does the calculation. As it is only the closest you are interested in the distances can remain as squares. The distance from the camera is held as a unit distance along the ray.

```
function distanceFromRay() { 
    var dSqr, ox, oy, oz, vx, vy, vz;
    function distanceSqr(px, py, pz) {
        const ax = px - ox, ay = py - oy, az = pz - oz;
        const u = (ax * vx + ay * vy + az * vz) / dSqr;        
        distanceSqr.unit = u;
        if (u > 0) { // is past origin
            const bx = ox + vx * u - px, by = oy + vy * u - py, bz = oz + vz * u - pz;
            return bx * bx + by * by + bz * bz; // dist sqr to closest point on ray 
        }
        return Infinity;
    }
    distanceSqr.unit = 0;
    distanceSqr.setRay(x, y, z, xx, yy, zz) { // ray from origin x, y,z, 
                                              // infinite length along xx,yy,zz
       (ox = x, oy = y, oz = z);
       (vx = xx, vy = yy, vz = zz);
       dSqr = vx * vx + vy * vy + vz * vz;
    }
    return distanceSqr;
}
```

### Usage

There is a one time setup call;

```
// setup
const distToRay = distanceFromRay();
```

At the start of a frame that requires a pick, calculate the pick ray and set it. Also set the min distance from ray and eye.

```
// at start of frame set pick  ray
distToRay.setRay(eye.x, eye.y, eye.z, pointer.ray.x, pointer.ray.y, pointer.ray.y);
var minDist = maxObjRadius * maxObjRadius;
var nearestObj = undefined;
var eyeDist = Infinity;
```

Then for each pickable object get the distance by passing the objects center and comparing it to any previous (in frame) found distance, objects radius, and distance from eye.

```
// per object
const dis = distToRay(obj.pos.x, obj.pos.y, obj.pos.z);
if (dis < obj.radius && dis < minDist && distToRay.unit > 0 && distToRay.unit < eyeDist ) {
    minDist = dis;
    eyeDist = distToRay.unit;
    nearestObj = obj;
}
```

At the end of the frame if `nearestObj` is not `undefined` it will hold a reference to the picked object.

```
// end of frame
if (nearestObj) {
    // you have the closest object
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think your solution relies on an undefined variable: ray. I have a nice working solution using my approach at gpsanimator.com/orbits.